# Turn number in to it's alphabet character equivalent in Applescript

Tags: applescript

How do I turn a number in to the equivalent letter? Like this?

```
0 => a
1 => b
2 => c
3 => d
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't require a look-up list...

```
set aNum to 0
set theChar to character id (aNum + 97)
```

If you're also interested in capital letters something like this would do...

```
set aNum to 0
set lowerCaseNum to 97
set upperCaseNum to 65

set lowercaseChar to character id (aNum + lowerCaseNum)
set uppercaseChar to character id (aNum + upperCaseNum)
return {lowercaseChar, uppercaseChar}
```

Comment: @dot I see in your comment to adayzdone that you wanted to have AA=27. Does this code solve that for you? I do not get 27 as a result when I assign 27 to aNum.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
property letters : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

set myNumber to 0
return text (myNumber + 1) of letters
-- returns a
```

Comment: thanks! would it be possible to have it go to AA for the number 27? right now it gives an error after the alphabet runs out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
on coerceNumToTime(theNum)
    set x to date ("0" as string)
    set hours of x to theNum div hours
    set minutes of x to theNum mod hours div minutes
    set seconds of x to theNum mod hours mod minutes
    return time string of x
end coerceNumToTime

set myNumber to 28
if myNumber < 26 then


    set lowerCaseNum to 97
    set upperCaseNum to 65
    set uppercaseChar to character id (myNumber + upperCaseNum)
else if myNumber > 27 then
    set myNumber to myNumber - 28

    set lowerCaseNum to 97
    set upperCaseNum to 65
    set uppercaseChar to character id (myNumber + upperCaseNum)
    set uppercaseChar to ("A" & uppercaseChar) as text

end if




return {uppercaseChar}
```